# How to run ShellCommandActivity on my own EC2 instance?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to run a simple command to test a ShellCommandActivity with Data Pipeline from AWS.

```
>>> /usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/script.py
```

That script should create a file on a S3, I know I could create a S3 file using the same Data Pipeline, but I want to test how to execute the script.

When I execute the pipeline I get this error:

> /usr/bin/python: can't open file '/home/ubuntu/script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

This is because AWS DP create a complete new EC2 instance when it runs, and my `script.py` is not there.

I created a Resource EC2
[image]

But there is not a field to define my own EC2 instance. How can I do this? Or maybe there some other way to approach this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is directly execute script.py
like

"command": "script.py"

Be sure your script.py with header

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: `script.py` does not exists in the created EC2.

Answer (score -1):

The script has to be placed on S3 and provide the path (//S3:....) in the script uri of the ShellCommandActivity